# Clustering algorithm for detecting colored objects

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation

Is it possible to use any clustering algorithm, to divide objects into 2 clusters based on their colours using opencv, to be able to count number of 2 different colored(colors are not exactly same for all objects, but they are similar) objects in an image?

So far, the following code is what I have achieved

`def getThresholdsKmeans(imageFile):
    im = cv2.imread(imageFile);
    im = ndimage.gaussian_filter(im,10)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    gray = gray.ravel();
    gray =  np.float32(gray);
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS +   cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,10,1);
    flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS;

    compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(gray,3,criteria,10,0)
    print centers
    return centers`

I use the values returned by function and threshold the image.

Comment: Additional hint: I would suggest to cluster in HSV/HSL color space (hue channel)

Comment: Have a look at **image segmentation**, instead of clustering.

Comment: Maybe show us an image so we understand better what you have and what you want? The solution you get will likely be better with better information provided by you.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hz0qm.jpg. 
This sample image is just one of these kinds. Since the background, blue and brown colors vary for different images, i'm trying to preprocess the image to get the threshold values for blue and brown. At the moment I can get these values, but sometimes kmeans does not yield accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cv::kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html). 
For each pixel, extract the three color values and insert them to the `data` matrix.
This results in a matrix with *number of pixel in the input image* rows and three columns.
Use this matrix as `data` parameter. The paramter `K` would be 2 or 3 depending on your definition (two colored objects + background color?).